# Mock a void method called from constructor

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito, powermock

I have the following class under test. I need to mock a method call- estabilishConnection from constructor, which returns void.

```````````````````````````
 public class ClassToBeTested {



    private ClassToBeMocked classToBeMocked;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    ClassToBeTested(ClassToBeMocked classToBeMocked, String name){
      this.classToBeMocked = classToBeMocked;
      this.name = name;
      age = this.getAge(name);
      this.estabilishConnection();
    }

    private int getAge(String name){
      int age =  (int) classToBeMocked.getNameAgeMap().get(name);
      return age;
    }

    private void estabilishConnection(){
            ``````````````````````````
            ````````````````````````
     }


}
```````````````````````````

Below given is the method that I have tried. But it is not working

```
    @Test
    public void testMethodInClassToBeMocked(){
      ClassToBeMocked mockApp = Mockito.mock(ClassToBeMocked.class);
      HashMap testMap= new HashMap();
      testMap.put("xys", 11);
      Mockito.when(mockApp.getNameAgeMap()).thenReturn(testMap);
      ///PowerMockito for mocking the void method

        PowerMockito.spy(ClassToBeTested.class);
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(ClassToBeTested.class, "estabilishConnection");

      ClassToBeTested classTest = new ClassToBeTested(mockApp, "xys");

      //Assertion of method in the test class goes here
    }
```

How can I make the method estabiishConnection to do nothing?

Comment: like a "deja vu" feeling....

Answer (score 1):

PowerMockito.stub(PowerMockito.method(ClassToBeTested.class, "estabilishConnection")).toReturn("nothing");

This one solved the issue